# Laravel run task every hour on 08:00, 12:00, 16:00 and 20:00, 22:00

Tags: php, laravel

I need schedule my task every hour on 08:00, 12:00, 16:00 and 20:00, 22:00. How I can do it?

Now I set:

```
$schedule->command(vkliketime::class)
            ->hourly()
            ->between('8:00', '22:00');
```

But this is not correct, I need run task only in times `08:00, 12:00, 16:00 and 20:00, 22:00`

Answer (score 0):

I’d create a foreach loop for this, like:

```
$hours=[“08:00”, “12:00”, “16:00”, “20:00”, “22:00”];
foreach($hours as $hour) {
$schedule->command(vkliketime::class)
        ->dailyAt($hour);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a less readable option using the `cron()` function.

```
$schedule
   ->command('vkliketime::class')
   ->cron('0 0 8,12,16,20,22 ? * * *');
```

But from what I can gather a simple loop like Zoli provided would be preferable.